# how to represent multiplicty of prime factor in factorization in python

Tags: python, python-requests, integer, format, factorization

I code this function factorization(n)... like below

```
def factorization(n):
    factor=[]
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        while n % i == 0:
            n = n/i
            factor.append(i)
        print(factor)
```

and if you write this
factorization(180) = [2,2,3,3,5]
but i want to print this format:
180 = 2^2 x 3^2 x 5

but i cant make it.
i think 'list counting' is useful but i don't know how to use it correctly the number of each factor, and format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using vanilla python & some formatting:

```
def factorization(n):
    factor = []
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        while n % i == 0:
            n = n / i
            factor.append(i)
    print('*'.join(f'{n}' + (f'^{factor.count(n)}' if factor.count(n) > 1 else '') for n in set(factor)))


factorization(180)
```

Prints:

```
2^2*3^2*5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use collections.Counter: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

```py
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(factorization(180))
counts[2]
counts[3]
```